# setting a javascript variable to a struts property map value

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

basically I want to do the following.

```
var myvar = '<s:property value="myMap['mapKey'].mapObjectValue" />'
```

but that fails.  I've tried several variations of quotes and can't quite get it to work correctly.  any ideas?

I can do this:

```
var myVar = <s:property value="myMap['mapKey'].mapObjectValue" />;
```

but then the javascript variable isn't a string, so I can't use it as needed.

Comment: How exactly did it fail? Did the IDE show a scary error which caused that you didn't even try to run it?

Answer (score 2):

If your first attempt is failing, I'm guessing that the problem is in the Javascript parsing.  You might want to try escaping the string for Javascript, using Apache Commons Lang for example:

```
var myvar = '<s:property value="@org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils@escapeJavaScript(myMap['mapKey'].mapObjectValue)" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be working, as the tag will be rendered before Javascript gets interpreted. If javascript value isn't getting setted properly, maybe

```
<s:property value="myMap['mapKey'].mapObjectValue" />
```

isn't returning the correct value.

As @BalusC said, theres is no need to make javascript compile on your IDE.